# How can I debug android native library with ida demo?

Tags: ida, android, shared-object

I am trying to debug android native library using ida demo version everything otherthing is working except some one I can't find android_server file for keeping on android device and can't see the debugger menu. I tried to follow many posts.

Answer (score 1):

IDA demo does not include remote debuggers so you can't debug Android programs with it. You need the full version.

Answer (score 0):

Eval version - https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml you are probably not using Windows.

> The MS Windows version contains a demo version of the ARM/Windows CE
>   debugger.  Please see our ARM/Windows CE debugging tutorial

Freeware - no luck https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml

Comment: But I can't see the debugger option in ida I want to debug android application native library